# what are the differences between `event.sender.send` and `webContents.send` in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

As this code snippet showed, both method can send event to the render process. I am wondering what are the differences between line A and line B in the code?

```
ipcMain.on('async', (event, arg) => {          
    console.log(arg);      
    event.sender.send('async-reply', 2); // line A
});


ipcMain.on('sync', (event, arg) => {          
    console.log(arg);
    event.returnValue = 4;
    mainWindow.webContents.send('ping', 5); //line B
});
```

Answer (score 5):

- `mainWindow.webContents.send`: sends an event to the `mainWindow`
- `event.sender.send`: sends an event to the window that sent it. So if you only use one window then they're virtually the same

I would use `event.sender.send` over `mainWindow.webContents.send` unless you want to send an event to a specific window.

And `event.returnValue = data` makes it synchronous so you can use `var data = ipcRenderer.sendSync('get-data');`